# Making symmetry of a BinaryTree

Tags: java

```
public static int mirror(BinaryNode<Integer> root)
   {

       if(root==null)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       else
       {
           root.setRight(root.getLeft());  
            mirror(root.getLeft());
            mirror(root.getRight());
        }
       return 0;
   }
```

input  4261357 (level order traversal)

```
      4
     / \
    2   6
   / \ / \
  1  3 5  7
```

output 4221111 (level order traversal)

```
      4
     / \
    2   2
   / \ / \
  1  1 1  1
```

But I want to mirror left to right

```
      4
     / \
    2   2
   / \ / \
  1  3 3  1
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: What should happen when the tree is one level deeper? And when there are missing nodes in the last level?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap both parts:

```
        temp = root.getLeft();
        root.setLeft(root.getRight());  
        root.setRight(temp); 

        mirror(root.getLeft());
        mirror(root.getRight());
```